# Jquery implementation not working on page reload

Tags: functions, theme-development, jquery

I am currently working on a theme for wordpress and I would like to implement this script:

```
   $('.graph-button').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active-animation");
    $(this).next().toggleClass("visible");
});
```

I currently have enqued the scripts and jquery is already loaded. But the script only works once on page load, then stops working. I know that wordpress uses a no conflict wrapper for jquery, Do i have to take any other steps to ensure the script does not break? I appreciate the help.

Comment: do you have this inside of a `$( document ).ready(function() {  your code });` construct?

Comment: Not `jquery( document ).ready(function($) {  your code });` ?

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook    Yes i have it wrapped in jquery( document ).ready(function($) { });

Comment: And no JavaScript errors in your browser once it fails?

Comment: Could the element you make visible be covering the element you click preventing any further click events on it?

Comment: I get no errors in the dev console. I also checked to see if something is covering the element and its not.